# Anywhere Access with Windows Server 2012 Essentials

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have Windows Server 2012 Essentials and I'm trying to set up Anywhere Access so I can remotely access files.  This feature was really easy to access in Windows Home Server and I'm trying to duplicate that functionality here.  
I've tried going through the Anywhere Access wizard several times but I can't get past the SSL Certificates step.  I don't want to purchase a certificate; is there any other way to enable remote file access?

Comment: You could always just  map a drive from your local machine when you create a remote desktop connection and drag and drop files from the windows server to and from your machine. It will appear as a normal drive on the windows server